# Clamping lines without '-webkit-line-clamp'

Tags: css, webkit, flexbox

In the good old days, there existed a trick in webkit for clamping lines using pure css:

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 3;
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Though this syntax happily coexists with the `display: -webkit-flex` syntax, in all modern webkit-based browsers, it is considered obsolete.

**My question is:**

How can I achieve line clamping in pure CSS and without the obsolete `'-webkit-line-clamp'` trick?

Comment: Do you need it to be a flex container *and* be clamped to 3 lines?  Or just be clamped to 3 lines?  The line-clamp property is a Webkit proprietary thing and has nothing to do with Flexbox specification.  It just happens to only work on an element with the `box` display property.

Comment: @cimmanon, good point, have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: The only cross-browser solution is to use js afaik. Several solutions to the problem of multi-line truncation with ellipsis are discussed here: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/ I hate them all, but welcome to web development.

Comment: how to get rid of -webkit? waiting until it becomes a fully adapted standard and drinking tea (und just using -webkit in the meanwhile, everybody should use chrome anyway)

Comment: Is there an official line that states that `-webkit-line-clamp` is obsolete?

Answer (score 32):

The only cross-browser solution is to use js afaik. Several solutions to the problem of multi-line truncation with ellipsis are discussed here: http://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

I hate them all, but welcome to web development.

Answer (score 8):

Try using this CSS

```
.line-clamp:after {
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), #FFFFFF 50%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
bottom: 0;
content: "...";
font-weight: bold;
padding: 0 20px 1px 45px;
position: absolute;
right: 0;}

.line-clamp {
height: 5.6em;
line-height: 1.4em;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;}
```

Comment: Tried this at https://codepen.io/alfred3x/pen/EXpBra?editors=1100. Two problems: 1- the ellipsis is sometimes quite far from the text. 2- If the text actually fits, the ellipsis still appears. So, I guess I'm still going to need a JS solution.

Answer (score 5):

The CSS Overflow Level 3 specification [defines a standard `line-clamp`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#line-clamp) property (without the quirks the ´-webkit-` prefixed solution has). Unfortunately, non of the main browsers supports this feature yet.

So, for now you will have to use a polyfill for browsers that don't support this property. [CSS-Tricks describes three solutions](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/), each one having its pros and cons.

1. Using standard CSS

   ```
   .fade {
     position: relative;
     height: 3.6em; /* exactly three lines */
   }

   .fade::after {
     content: "";
     text-align: right;
     position: absolute;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     width: 70%;
     height: 1.2em;
     background:
       linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 50%);
   }
   ```

   Pros: All current browsers support this.
   Cons: There's a fade-out instead of an ellipsis and requires heights to be set manually.
2. Using Opera's `-o-ellipsis-lastline` value

   ```
   .last-line {
     height: 3.6em; /* exactly three lines */
     text-overflow: -o-ellipsis-lastline;
   }
   ```

   Pros: Display as expected.
   Cons: Only works in old versions of Opera and requires height to be set manually
3. Using JavaScript ([Clamp.js](https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js))

   ```
   var module = document.getElementById("clamp-this-module");
   $clamp(module, {clamp: 3});
   ```

   Pros: Display as expected and is flexible through different options.
   Cons: Requires a JS library to work and is less performant than CSS solutions.

Answer (score 4):

It's worth noting that as of late 2019 the original premise of this question – i.e. that the `-webkit-line-clamp` is obsolete – may no longer be true.

According to [Elad's article](https://medium.com/@elad/trimming-multi-lines-in-css-5ae59d5e6d84), both Edge and Firefox have introduced support for the rather useful `-webkit` syntax, making it the closest thing we'll have to a standard. To me, the chances of Microsoft and Firefox ever being pragmatic enough to support the webkit prefix seems remote. However, now that they have, I'd expect it to remain for the foreseeable future.

I haven't tested it extensively on Edge yet, but it's rock-solid on Safari, Chrome and Firefox – though you should avoid padding-bottom.

Comment: The css-tricks "line-clampin" article mentioned in several of these posts has also been updated to consider this method the standard, given its support on everything but IE.

Comment: `-webkit-line-clamp` still requires [`-webkit-box-orient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient) which throws a deprecation warning in Firefox as of October 2023