# How to text-overflow an absolute positioned span inside a div on the 2nd line?

Tags: html, css

I want this description text to have `text-overflow: ellipsis` on the second line. but it seems my code doesn't work.

```
<div class="container">
  <span
    >Test test test testTest test test testTest test test testTest test test
    testTest test test testTest test test testTest test test test</span
  >
</div>
```

and the css part (note: a relative positioned container is required in this case)

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 320px;
    height: 220px;
    background-image: url("https://terrigen-cdn-dev.marvel.com/content/prod/1x/popsicle_heroesscreenshot_legal.jpg");
  }

  span {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    bottom: 32px;
    left: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-clamp: 2;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on this, but it seems `line-clamp` is the issue. Sadly, [`line-clamp` is still in draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#line-clamp) and has no support yet.

Please [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53008608/3931225) for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem, `line-clamp: 2` should be with prefixed with *-webkit*. And need to add two properties `display: -webkit-box`, `-webkit-box-orient: vertical` without this combination `line-clamp` doesn't works.
`text-overflow: ellipsis` you can delete.

```
span {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  bottom: 32px;
  left: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /*changed */
  /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */ /* can be remove */
  display: -webkit-box; /* new line */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical; /* new line */
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  height: 220px;
  background-image: url('https://terrigen-cdn-dev.marvel.com/content/prod/1x/popsicle_heroesscreenshot_legal.jpg');
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  bottom: 32px;
  left: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2; /*changed */
  /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */ /* can be remove */
  display: -webkit-box; /* new line */
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical; /* new line */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Test test test testTest test test testTest test test testTest test test testTest test test
        testTest test test testTest test test test</span
      >
    </div>
```